# Custom chart elements

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I want to make a chart in C# with custom elements. What  I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Elements marked by red circles need to be replaced by the image. My program code is very short, just some values for the chart. All settings for chart were set by the "Collection" in Chart section (as shown on first image).

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: Also: Do describe (or draw red circles) exactly which elements you mean. What does _the "Collection" in Chart section_ mean??

Comment: I edited the post. Maybe now problem is more clear to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [BoxPlot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456709.aspx) chart and it takes 6 y-values.

You can add them or let the chart calculate them.

Looks like you want to add several images to the various y-values..

Here is an example of how to do that by owner-drawing the Chart. (No, not the whole chart, just a little extra custom-drawing ;-)

It adds an image to **each** of the y-values; it should be easy to adapt to only those values you really want. And if you only want one you may even do away with the `ImageList` and pick the image from the resources; (although using an `ImageList` is a nice way, as long as you can live with the limitations of 256x256 maximum size and all images having the same size and color depth..)

You seem to want one of these only:

> 4      Average and mean
>
> 5      Median

```
private void chart_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Series s1 = chart.Series[0];
    ChartArea ca = chart.ChartAreas[0];
    Axis ax = ca.AxisX;
    Axis ay = ca.AxisY;
    Graphics g = e.ChartGraphics.Graphics;
    int iw = imageList1.ImageSize.Width / 2;
    int ih = imageList1.ImageSize.Height / 2;
    foreach (DataPoint dp in s1.Points)
    {
        int x = (int) ax.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.XValue);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            int y = (int) ay.ValueToPixelPosition(dp.YValues[i]);
            g.DrawImage(imageList1.Images[i], x - iw, y - ih);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I suggest to use `png` files with transparency and an odd width so they look nice and centered. (I used randomly 16x16, which is not quite that nice ;-)  - For this you need to set the `ImageSize` and the `ColorDepth` of the `ImageList`.

To further style the chart you may use these special properties

> Custom attributes
>
> BoxPlotPercentile, BoxPlotSeries, BoxPlotShowAverage,
>   BoxPlotShowMedian, BoxPlotShowUnusualValues, BoxPlotWhiskerPercentile,
>   DrawSideBySide, MaxPixelPointWidth, MinPixelPointWidth,
>   PixelPointDepth, PixelPointGapDepth, PixelPointWidth, PointWidth

Note that you need to set them all as strings, maybe like this:

```
  s1.SetCustomProperty("someAttribute", "someValue");
```